# send output of batch file with adb commands to vbscript

Tags: android, batch-file, vbscript, adb

This shouldn't be tough, but my knowledge is very limited.

I would like to get the values returned by the following adb commands:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.brand
adb shell getprop ro.product.model
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
```

and assign the values to variables which are passed into a **vbscript**.

I have tried without success:

```
set adb shell getprop ro.product.brand=deviceBrand
echo %deviceBrand&
```

This is really two issues (1. assign variable, 2. pass to vbscript). I am just looking for help on step 1. here.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Aacini I now have the adb commands as variable using [For /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html). Below is my current code:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb devices') do set devices=%%a

rem get the values returned by the following adb commands into variables:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer') do set mfg=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.brand') do set brand=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.PDA') do set pda=%%a 
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.model') do set model=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release') do set os=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.locale.language') do set language=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.locale.region') do set region=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.target_country') do set country=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.target_operator') do set operator=%%a
for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('adb shell dumpsys package com.my.package1^|find "version"') do set package1=%%a
for /F "tokens=1 delims=" %%a in ('adb shell dumpsys package com.my.package2^|find "version"') do set package2=%%a
```

However, I am still getting lost passing it to vbscript. With the code Aacini provided, I expected to see a file created called "theScript.vbs", but I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rem get the values returned by the following adb commands into variables:
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.brand') do set brand=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.product.model') do set model=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release') do set version=%%a

rem pass these variables into a vbscript:
cscript //nologo theScript.vbs
```

Into TheScript.vbs:

```
set wshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set env = wshell.Environment("PROCESS")
set brand = env("brand")
set model = env("model")
set version = env("version")
```

I am not totally sure of the VBS syntax to get the value of variables, but a search on [this site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156595.aspx)
will give specific details.

Comment: Thanks. This works for saving adb results as variables. I'll need to look into the vbscript a little more to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by Storing values in temp. File and read from the file or Setting value in Environment variable of OS.